# How to select the region between two ring? (annulus)

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

When I press "F" at this time, the face created are always inside the inner ring[image]

Comment: it seems already selected, just switch to face select mode...

Comment: @m.ardito that's a strong point (°ー°〃)

Comment: reading again, I don't understand,  probably. I tried and I can't reproduce your setup. You have the "grey" cylinder, and then two rings of connected vertices that could be either "part" (ie:  a portion) of the cylinder's upper circular face, OR just two "indipendent" rings of connected vertices that you have drawn just upon the  cylinder's upper circular face.

Comment: It seems you're in vertices select mode but that  cylinder's upper circular face  shows no edges apart the border ones... but it doesn't seem an n-gon either...? but you say that F creates faces "always inside the inner ring" (I don't get this,too...) I'm quite curious about how you got that setup, the base cylinder and the two rings above...? Or can you share that file as it is above on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (then edit your question and add the provided link)?

Comment: @m.ardito Oh it's just creating a cylinder, and then inset the upper circle and then inset again(ノ°ο°)ノ

Comment: can't reproduce sorry. I select the upper circle (a single n-gon face) then press I (inset) and it that extrudes the border edges toward the center, creating a ring of faces, but leaving in thre center the (smaller) single n-gon face. Repeating, it does the same, another ring of faces, but always a (even smaller) single n-gon face inside. Not as in your picture. Sorry, can't get it.

Comment: @m.ardito wierd though, I tried again with same steps and it automatically selected what I want=͟͟͞͞(꒪⌓꒪*)

Answer (score 1):

it seems like outer ring is "hovering" over the cylinder and is not a part of it. in that case use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to create faces between those two rings.

Comment: And then do Alt J, because Alt F is likely going to create triangles everywhere, Alt J will quadrangulate the mesh.